# MySQL display results alphabetical order but show a particular item before the alphabetical sorted list

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a list in MySQL that is sorted in alphabetical order as follows.

1. Argentina
2. Brazil
3. China
4. Malta
5. USA

Since the magority of my customers are from the USA, I want it to be displayed first in the list e.g.

1. USA
2. Argentina
3. Brazil
4. China
5. Malta

This is my code -

```
$sqlprimaryCategory = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tableName GROUP BY primary_category ");
```

This is what I tried but did not work - 
    $sqlprimaryCategory = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tableName GROUP BY primary_category ORDER BY primary_category='USA' ASC, primary_category ASC");

Comment: I have found that it is best to alter the physical data: numbered 1 to 5, where 1 is USA and the rest is alphabetical order. That way you need not alter the table and just need to fetch.

Comment: The above example using country names is an example. Instead of countries I will be using product categories, so I will be adding product categories all the time so if I want certain product categories to appear on top it will be a tedious task to stay renumbering them all the time.

Comment: are they stored in the database with a number?

Comment: they are stored in MySQL using auto increment since this is mandatory

Comment: so its an id that is autoincremented and the name is in a different column right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do a conditional order by with a case statement like so

## QUERY:

```
SELECT * 
FROM $tableName 
GROUP BY primary_category
ORDER BY 
    CASE primary_category WHEN 'USA' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC,
    primary_category ASC
```

## EDIT:

if you want to order by multiple fields first and then the rest you can do it like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM $tableName 
GROUP BY primary_category
ORDER BY 
    CASE primary_category 
      WHEN 'USA' THEN 1 --#-- 1 for usa
      WHEN 'China' THEN 2 --#-- 2 for china
      ELSE 3 END ASC, --#-- 3 for anything else
    primary_category ASC
```

Comment: @user2333968 sure thing! remember if you want to add more than one order you can do that too.. i'll give an example as well :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a greater problem here. Your logic.

If there are numerous high priority product categories, then clearly you will need another column `priority TINYINT(1)`.

Then select...`ORDER BY priority DESC, category`