# select max sum of records in two columns

Tags: mysql, sum, max

I need to select team that is the top scorer in the league. this is the match column, it does depends on m_id if you are team1_id or team2_id same with scores as there are rematches too in the league.

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `xeg8u_bl_match` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `m_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `team1_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `team2_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `score1` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `score2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `match_descr` text NOT NULL,
  `published` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_extra` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `m_played` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `m_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `m_time` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `m_location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bonus1` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `bonus2` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `team1_strzaly` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team1_strzalyc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team1_posiadanie` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team1_przejecia` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team1_faule` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team1_zkartki` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team1_ckartki` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team1_kontuzje` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team1_spalone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team1_rrozne` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team1_celnosc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team1_dpodan` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team2_strzaly` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team2_strzalyc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team2_posiadanie` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team2_przejecia` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team2_faule` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team2_zkartki` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team2_ckartki` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team2_kontuzje` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team2_spalone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team2_rrozne` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team2_celnosc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `team2_dpodan` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=399 ;
```

Now I was thinking about using two function in SELECT, MAX and SUM, I was trying to get this but I have no idea how I can get this to work, I know how to display goals scored home and away for specified team but I dont know how can I check which team is a top scorrer. Any ideas?

So I work it out an it does work however my question is if there is any way to do it easier and if it is needed to do it different way?

```
    //season_id
$link = ConnectToMySql();
$wynik = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT season_id FROM xeg8u_bl_season_teams WHERE team_id = '$teamekid' LIMIT 1");
$m_id = mysqli_fetch_array($wynik);
$r4 = $m_id[0];

//sprawdzam jakie id dni meczowych znajdują się w sezonie o id x
$link = ConnectToMySql();
$wynik = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT MIN(id) FROM xeg8u_bl_matchday WHERE s_id = '$r4'");
$m_id = mysqli_fetch_array($wynik);
$min_r1 = $m_id[0];

$link = ConnectToMySql();
$wynik = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT MAX(id) FROM xeg8u_bl_matchday WHERE s_id = '$r4'");
$m_id = mysqli_fetch_array($wynik);
$max_r1 = $m_id[0];

$link = ConnectToMySql();
$wynik = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT m_id FROM xeg8u_bl_match WHERE m_id LIKE '$r1'");
$id = mysqli_fetch_array($wynik);
$r2 = $id[0];



$link = ConnectToMySql();
$wynik = mysqli_query($link, "Select team, sum(score) as totalscore from (select team1_id as team, sum(score1) as score from xeg8u_bl_match WHERE m_id BETWEEN '$min_r1' AND '$max_r1' group by team1_id union all select team2_id as team, sum(score2) as score from xeg8u_bl_match WHERE m_id BETWEEN '$min_r1' AND '$max_r1' group by team2_id) as scores group by team order by totalscore asc limit 1");
$krol = mysqli_fetch_array($wynik);
$r3 = $krol[0];
```

Is that fine to leave it like this or there is a simpler, better looking way to do it?

Comment: It's nice that you have posted your table structure... but [have you tried anything regarding the solution of your problem?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please post your attempts

Comment: As I have wrote, I was trying but no ideas how can I do this, I did mentioned that I was using a Max and Sum functions but no lack does it needed to be so arrogant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you need this:

```
select team, sum(score) as totalscore
from
(
    select team1_id as team, sum(score1) as score
    from xeg8u_bl_match
    group by team1_id
    union all
    select team2_id as team, sum(score2) as score
    from xeg8u_bl_match
    group by team2_id
) as scores
group by team
order by 2 desc
limit 1
```

Comment: `order by 2`? wouldn't it be `order by totalscore desc`?

Comment: @Barranka I don't remember exactly whether mysql understand aliases in order by

Comment: Thank you very much Lashane, I would never get this that way.

Comment: you can order by an alias in mysql but order by 2 is a completely acceptable way to do it too

Comment: @barranka yes you can reference the alias in group by order by or having clause... Think of it this way.. Select from join and where is the order for food.. Group by order by and having is when the order is completed and you are manipulating what's already been produced.. Because the alias has already been pulled out as a "column" you can reference it :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell what I meant is that I didn'k know that you could use something like `order by 2`... I know you can use `order by alias` (and having `[condition on alias]`... but... `order by 2` is new to me

Comment: @Barranka yea.. so when you order by a count what are you doing? ordering by a number.. so you can just write the number in there if you want.. that will show all 2's then 1's... see my answer here for a conditional order by that puts in a number for specific cases :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193674/mysql-display-results-alphabetical-order-but-show-a-particular-item-before-the-a/25193811#25193811

Comment: Right guys, now I have a problem, I forgot ot mention that this table contains all of the matches, form all leagues and cups. Now how I can do restrict this function to give me a results from this table for the "season" league that this team is in? the table that contains which match day contains which matches and which season/league they belongs to loks like this
id,m_name,m_descr,s_id,is_playoff
Where m_id from match table is same as id column from match_day table and s_id contains the season id.??

Comment: Basically I do have variable $teamekid that gives me id of the team maybe something with that I can do?

Comment: @JohnRuddell order by 2 in this case - order by 2nd column, not by number 2

Comment: @PawełGawroński to filter rows by you need to use `where` statement

Comment: yes I know this, but when Im trying to add where to the select that you give me it give me an error

Select md.id, m.m_id, team, sum(score) as totalscore from xeg8u_bl_matchday as md, xeg8u_bl_match as m (select team1_id as team, sum(score1) as score from xeg8u_bl_match group by team1_id union all select team2_id as team, sum(score2) as score from xeg8u_bl_match group by team2_id) as scores WHERE m.m_id=md.id group by team order by totalscore desc limit 1

Comment: @PawełGawroński so it is time to learn sql and when you will have actual problem - post question to this site